# start mysqld acting strange

Tags: mysql, centos, centos7

After installing `mysql-community-server-8.0.17-1.el7.x86_64` on centos 7, I tried to run `systemctl start mysqld` which gave me this:

```
//ERROR MESSAGE 1
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I ran `systemctl status mysqld.service -l` and the result was:

```
 mysqld.service - MySQL Server
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-09-29 22:54:21 IST; 1min 5s ago
 Docs: man:mysqld(8)
       http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
 Process: 5025 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Process: 4991 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5025 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Status: "Server startup in progress"
 Error: 13 (Permission denied)

 Sep 29 22:53:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
 Sep 29 22:54:19 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5025]: 2019-09-29T17:24:19.458682Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 5025
 Sep 29 22:54:19 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5025]: 2019-09-29T17:24:19.575176Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file '/var/log/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
 Sep 29 22:54:19 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5025]: 2019-09-29T17:24:19.625828Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
 Sep 29 22:54:19 localhost.localdomain mysqld[5025]: 2019-09-29T17:24:19.626927Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
 Sep 29 22:54:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Sep 29 22:54:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
 Sep 29 22:54:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
 Sep 29 22:54:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Then I changed to permission of `mysql.log` to `777` but after again `start`ing `mysqld` I again received `ERROR MESSAGE 1` (check above)

This time the status was:

```
 mysqld.service - MySQL Server
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-09-29 22:56:14 IST; 8s ago
 Docs: man:mysqld(8)
       http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
 Process: 5110 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Process: 5077 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5110 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Status: "Server startup in progress"
 Error: 2 (No such file or directory)

 Sep 29 22:56:04 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
 Sep 29 22:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Sep 29 22:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
 Sep 29 22:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
 Sep 29 22:56:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

Then I checked `/var/log/mysqld.log` which contained:

```
 2019-09-29T17:35:14.918779Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) initializing of server in progress as process 5295
 2019-09-29T17:35:14.922106Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
 2019-09-29T17:35:14.922221Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
 2019-09-29T17:35:14.922316Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
 2019-09-29T17:35:14.922661Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Then I emptied the directory using `rm /var/lib/mysql/* -rf`, I emptied the `mysqld.log` and again tried to start `mysqld` then again `ERROR MESSAGE 1` got printed and the log file contained this:

```
2019-09-29T17:41:57.989709Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-09-29T17:41:57.990134Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-09-29T17:41:58.418384Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 5657
2019-09-29T17:41:59.007005Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2019-09-29T17:41:59.007190Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-09-29T17:41:59.007326Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-09-29T17:41:59.008559Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I understand it tons of data, what should I do?

Comment: Has your `mysql` user changed or something? Was the old version working correctly, and what was the old version?

Comment: @user3788685 There was none as i ran this command `yum remove mysql-server`

Comment: do you have selinux enabled? at a quick glance I can't tell whats happened. where did you get the new rpm - was it the official mysql repo?

Comment: @user3788685 I had it disabled

Comment: @user3788685 the rpm was from the official link